# How can I resolve the 'customMarker.ts:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined' error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the @googlemaps/react-wrapper library to implement Google Maps. To display a custom marker on the map, I declared the CustomMarker class as follows:

```
class CustomMarker extends google.maps.OverView {
   ( ... )
}
```

However, I encountered the following error:

> customMarker.ts:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined.

I believe the issue arises during the code evaluation phase because the Google library hasn't been loaded yet.

To resolve this error, I wrapped the class in an additional function:

```
const factory = () => {
class CustomMarker extends google.maps.OverView {
   ( ... )

return ({ uuid, label }: Options) => new CustomMarker({ uuid, label });
 }
}

// usage
function Marker({ marker, map }: MarkerProps) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!marker || !map) {
      return;
    }

    const { uuid, label } = marker;

    const customMarker = factory()({ uuid, label });

    customMarker.position = map.getCenter();
    customMarker.setMap(map);
  }, [map, marker]);

  return null;
}
```

However, I feel this approach is inefficient as the class is declared every time. Is there a better way to address this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue. A codesandbox link that the community can check would be nice to have.